# How to find a code that try to get access to nonexistent database column?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have a PostgreSQL database and .NET console app that work with the database.

When I try to create a record in a table "measurements", then I get an error "Column with name "Company_Id" doesn't exist in a table "measurements"" on _context.SaveChanges(measurement) line.

Yes, there is now such column in a table "measurements". However, there is no declaration "Company_Id" in my app code too.

This is my measurement context:

```
[Table("measurements", Schema = "public")]
public class Measurement
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("road_part_id")]
    public long RoadPartId { get; set; }

    [Column("is_direction_forward")]
    public bool IsDirectionForward { get; set; }

    [Column("start_distance")]
    public float StartDistance { get; set; }

    [Column("finish_distance")]
    public float FinishDistance { get; set; }

    [Column("lane_number")]
    public Int16 LaneNumber { get; set; }

    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("order_id")]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    [Column("builder_id")]
    public long BuilderId { get; set; }
}
```

So, I can't understand which code tries to access column "Company_Id" in a table "measurements". How can I find the source of the error?

Comment: There is possibly an unmapped or mismapped relationship between Company and Measurement that EF is expecting to associate a Company_ID on measurement instead of a Measurement_id on Company or such. Post up the Company entity and any relevant mapping configuration between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was "pgAdmin 4" bug, because when I simply create "Company_Id" column  and remove it, then my problem was fixed and no any errors occured.